# How to set the WCF binding scheme via code?

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-binding, wcf-configuration

I need to reproduce this `app.config` service file via `C#` code.

```
<system.serviceModel>
....
  <protocolMapping>
     <add scheme="https" binding="wsHttpBinding" />
  </protocolMapping>
...
```

Specially the `scheme` part, so i did this:

```
   var binding = new WSHttpBinding();
   binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.Transport;
   ...
```

But if i try to do a `binding.Scheme = ...` i get the compile time error `the property Scheme has no setter`.

How to set it via code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `binding.Scheme` is set automatically by the class when you set `binding.Security.Mode`. For instance, if you set `binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.None;`, then it returns `"http"` and if you set `binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.Transport;` then it returns `"https"`.

WSHttpBinding reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.wshttpbinding%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Also, if you google `setting up a wcf service in code` there seems to be lots of interesting examples to help you on your way.